# Raise ParseError in Haskell/Parsec

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

What is the prefered way to raise errors (`ParseError`) in Parsec? I got some code inside a parser that performs a check and if the check fails a `ParseError` should be returned (i.e. `Left ParseError` when running `parse`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Prim.unexpected`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/parsec/Text-ParserCombinators-Parsec-Prim.html#v%3Aunexpected) and [`Control.Monad.fail`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.1.0.0/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#v%3Afail) for this. Both take a `String` argument signifying the error message and will return (in this case) a value of type `GenParser tok st a`.

For more, see [`Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Error`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.0.1/doc/html/Text-ParserCombinators-Parsec-Error.html#t%3AMessage), specifically [`Message`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.0.1/doc/html/Text-ParserCombinators-Parsec-Error.html#t%3AMessage). There you can read which function to use in which case (though both signify a parse error, they are semantically slightly different).

Comment: can you elaborate on how to combine these with parsers ? for example when having parser like this : `p=someparser <|> fail "error"` the thing is when someparser fails its error message doesn't go away, instead the string "error" gets appended to it.